# ExtJS Gridview multiple record selection on checkbox ONLY

Tags: gridview, extjs, multi-select

Please find the jsfiddle with the options I am using: http://jsfiddle.net/7bj4n/2/
    code sample:

```
   Ext.define('App.MyStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],
    data: [
        { 'name': 'Lisa', "email": "lisa@simpsons.com", "phone": "555-111-1224" },
        { 'name': 'Bart', "email": "bart@simpsons.com", "phone": "555-222-1234" },
        { 'name': 'Homer', "email": "home@simpsons.com", "phone": "555-222-1244"},
        { 'name': 'Lisa', "email": "lisa@simpsons.com", "phone": "555-111-1224" },
        { 'name': 'Bart', "email": "bart@simpsons.com", "phone": "555-222-1234" },
        { 'name': 'Homer', "email": "home@simpsons.com", "phone": "555-222-1244"},
        { 'name': 'Lisa', "email": "lisa@simpsons.com", "phone": "555-111-1224" },
        { 'name': 'Bart', "email": "bart@simpsons.com", "phone": "555-222-1234" },
        { 'name': 'Homer', "email": "home@simpsons.com", "phone": "555-222-1244"},
        { 'name': 'Lisa', "email": "lisa@simpsons.com", "phone": "555-111-1224" },
        { 'name': 'Bart', "email": "bart@simpsons.com", "phone": "555-222-1234" },
        { 'name': 'Homer', "email": "home@simpsons.com", "phone": "555-222-1244"},
        { 'name': 'Lisa', "email": "lisa@simpsons.com", "phone": "555-111-1224" },
        { 'name': 'Bart', "email": "bart@simpsons.com", "phone": "555-222-1234" },
        { 'name': 'Homer', "email": "home@simpsons.com", "phone": "555-222-1244"},
        { 'name': 'Lisa', "email": "lisa@simpsons.com", "phone": "555-111-1224" },
        { 'name': 'Bart', "email": "bart@simpsons.com", "phone": "555-222-1234" },
        { 'name': 'Homer', "email": "home@simpsons.com", "phone": "555-222-1244"}
    ]
});
Ext.define('App.MyGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.mygrid',
    title: 'Simpsons',
    width: 500,
    initComponent: function () {
        this.store = Ext.create('App.MyStore');
        this.selModel = Ext.create("Ext.selection.CheckboxModel", { 
            allowDeselect: true,
            //checkOnly : true,
            mode:'MULTI',
            listeners: {
                beforeselect: function(selModel, record, index){
                    //return false;
                    console.log('sm::beforeselect');   
                   // console.log(selModel);   

                },
                select: function(){
                    console.log('sm::select');                    
                }
            }
        });
        this.callParent(arguments);
    },
    columns: [
        { header: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name' },
        { header: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1 },
        { header: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone' }
    ]
});

Ext.onReady(function () {
    Ext.widget('mygrid', {
        title: 'First Panel',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        listeners: {
            itemclick: function(){
                console.log('itemclick');
            }
        }    
    });
});
```

Problem statement with example:

User is viewing the grid view of 5000 rows and let's say they want to select multiple rows randomly...let's say from 21-30, then 501-700 and 1201-1350 etc

currently they can do this by shift+select by clicking on the grid rows but if they happen to click anywhere in grid row/body or even right click their entire selection gets de-selected and ONLY the row where they happened to click/right-click gets selected, which is really annoying and they have to repeat the same selection process again...clearly not a good User experience.

So in short, 
I want to retain the multiple row selection using shift + select on whichever rows they want but make it functional ONLY on checkbox and disable that grid row/body click or right click.

P.S: "checkonly" option works on checkbox but it disables the multiple selection (shift + select)

Any suggestions?

Comment: try this article : http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/02/extjs-grid-checkcolumn-enable-disable.html

Comment: Oguz, thank you for taking your time to reply. Article you mentioned looked interesting but I don't see it being useful for my scenario. It talks about enabling/disabling checkcolumn based on row data.
I use gridview across various pages and it's configurable, all I need is multiple selection on checkbox only.

Comment: Dear friend, in my opinion, there is only one way to resolve this issue which is only disable checkbox status and changing the row background color.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs friend..I think I have figured it out.